# Changing php document root for a folder

Tags: php, apache

While i host my site online, i keep a local copy on my computer, which is running fedora 20 and apache server, for testing purposes. However i have stumbled trying to use the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable in php.

On my web server, the document root is: /var/www/httpdocs whereas on my computer the document root is: /var/www/html/mysite.

Is there a way to change the apache document root on my local server to be the same in the php variable?

Comment: Why should they be the same?

Comment: If you really must, then edit the DocumentRoot directive in httpd.conf then restart Apache.

Comment: I want them to be the same, because in a php script, when i am using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], the outcome will be different between the local and the remote server.

Comment: Why is this a problem? I cant think of a single case, where this might be a problem. I guess you are trying to solve an other problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to differentiate the production and development environments, a better way of doing that would be to create an environment variable that PHP will read and will then load the correct configurations for that environment.

You can set an environment variable by using the following instruction in your virtual host file:
SetEnv env-variable [value]

Read the variable in php by using [getenv function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php):

```
getenv ( string $varname )
```

You can read more about enviorment variables in apache in greater detail in [apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html).

Comment: i see your point, but i would really prefer to solve this one with an apache rewrite rule, or a change in virtual hosts config file